# Is this maritime plant a species of zostera?

Tags: species-identification

This photograph was taken on the intertidal mudflats at Lindisfarne, Northumberland, UK today. It was about 40m from the shoreline at low tide. Is the green plant a species of zostera? Can anyone help with the identification?

[image: species]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about plant identification. These questions are usually asked on Gardening and Landscaping Stack Exchange. This topic is not found in the following appropriate topics listing in the Help center: 1) General questions about biological concepts 2) Questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions 3) Questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Answer (score 3):

It certainly looks like a *Zostera* species.  The ones that appear in the UK are *Zostera angustifolia*, *Zostera noltii*, and *Zostera marina*.  Its hard to tell exactly which species this one is without size information and knowing the conditions of the bay.  *Z. marina* has the broadest leaves at around 5 - 10 mm, whilst *Z. angustifolia* has leaves just 2 - 3 mm broad.  Is 40m around the mid-water mark?  If so I would hazard a guess this is *Z. angustifolia*.  *Z. marina* tends to stick to areas permanently covered by the sea (sub-littoral) whilst *Z. noltii* likes much more sheltered conditions than the middle of the bay, tending to stick to the upper shore.

Hope that helps!